# How to send an Asynchronous post request with a parameter in objective -c?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlrequest

I am trying to send an asynchronous Post request to a php url, but the request requires a parameter of "Password" and a value of "EGOT". I am pretty sure I need to use this:

```
(void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
```

The only problem is that when I start to type it in my viewController implementation file, it does not get recognized. Do I need to import NSURL for this? I thought that UIVIewcontroller already inherits from the class. If this is not the proper method to get this request please explain to me how to get it, it'll be much appreciated.

Comment: By parameter you mean a request header?

Comment: You can start using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which is very easy to use wrapper class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your request object like this (`NSMutableURLRequest` is a mutable subclass of 'NSURLRequest'):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request addValue:@"EGOT" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Password"];
```

And then call `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` with that request.

Comment: Im sorry im just a little confused as to how to implement the sendAsynchronousRequest. after I did what you said I put in:        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:@"http://ec2-54-243-205-92.compute-1.amazonaws.com/Tests/ping.php" queue:request completionHandler:<#^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)handler#>{
        NSLog(@"worked");
    }];
}

Comment: The first parameter to `sendAsynchronousRequest`  should be an `NSMutableURLRequest` (like in my example), or else an `NSURLRequest`. It's not a string. See the docs for the method: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for Asynchronous request with post method...

```
NSString *strupload=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"uid=%@&password=%@&oldpassword=%@",appdel.strUserid,txtConfirmPswd.text,txtOldPswd.text];
NSString *strurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@change_password.php?",LocalPath];
NSString *strpostlength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[strupload length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlrequest=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];

[urlrequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strurl]];
[urlrequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlrequest setValue:strpostlength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[urlrequest setHTTPBody:[strupload dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlrequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     NSError *error1;
     NSDictionary *res=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error1];
 }];
```

Comment: This is amazing !

Answer (score 0):

You can use AFNetworking for upload and MBProgressHUD for progress display

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient                    = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlLink]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request;

request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                        path:nil
                                                  parameters:postDictionary
                                   constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
                                   }];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Uploading";

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        float uploadPercentge           = (float)totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
        float uploadActualPercentage    = uploadPercentge * 100;
        hud.progress                    = uploadPercentge;
        if (uploadActualPercentage >= 100) {
            hud.mode        = MBProgressHUDModeText;
            hud.labelText   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Waiting for response"];
        }
    }];
    [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];

    [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        [hud hide:YES];
        NSLog(@"Success %@",  operation.responseString);
        NSDictionary *message = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[operation.responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        DLog(@"%@",message);
    }
                                      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                          NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);
                                          NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                      }];
    [operation start];
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?